# как запустить игру winforms через браузер?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, winforms

Постигаю азы программирования. Создаю сайт-резюме, куда буду выкладывать свои проекты.
https://my1simplesite.000webhostapp.com/
Как можно сделать так, что б при нажатии кнопки "Source" (позже переименую в "Play") можно было запустить саму игру? Ира написана на шарпе с WinForms и запускается через путь .\bin\Debug\game.exe
на компьютере. Код для заполнения карты написан на js

```
export const projects = [
{
title: 'Просто игрушка',
description: "Попробовал освоить работу с WinForms. Как результат вышла эта простая игруля.",
  image: '/images/simple_game.jpg', 
  tags: ['C#', 'WinForms', 'Calculator'],
source: 'https://google.com',
visit: 'https://github.com/Peterblr/Simple_Game',
id: 0,
}]
```

Платный хостинг для выкладывания всего этого дела в тырнет по еще не осваивал. Сайт лежит на бесплатном 000webhost.
Как оживить кнопку "source", что б запускалась игра в браузере? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Никак. Windows Forms не предназначен для запуска в браузере. Максимум, вы можете предоставить ссылку для скачивания вашего приложение, а вот запустит его пользователь или нет - уже дело пользователя.

Comment: Можете gif'ку вставить с представлением игры

Comment: я так понимаю, что б поиграть в браузере нужно написать на JS?

Comment: Можно использовать Blazor - это позволит писать код на C#, который будет работать в браузере.

Comment: Я "плюсую" вопрос, потому что его задают себе тысячи компаний, использующих легаси - системы. Вообще, для резюме достаточно снять игровой процесс в виде ролика. а запуск винформс в браузере - довольно нетривиальная штука...

Answer (score 0):

Thinfinity VirtualUI

https://www.cybelesoft.com/blog/run-winforms-application-inside-web-browser/?cn-reloaded=1
https://www.cybelesoft.com/download/#tvui

Когда-то давно был ещё ASP.NET Web Forms, но это не совсем то.